# Duality in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I saw the some theorem.

1. If primal problem is unbounded 
   then no feasible solutions for dual.
2. If dual problem is unbounded
   then no feasible solutions for primal.

Please help me to understand above theorem

Comment: Strong duality and slater condition might help in understanding the theorem

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, I write this answer without any mathematical proof. 
If the primal problem is unbounded, it means that, there **doesnt** exist an $M$ such that $c^Tx \leq M, \forall x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ which are feasible.

So, your optimal value is $+\infty$.

The dual of the primal problem is minimization. As per the strong duality condition we have $p^* \leq d^*$, where $p^*$ is optimal for primal problem and $d^*$ is optimal for dual problem.

From the unbounded property of primal problem we have $p^*=+\infty$. Hence we should have $+\infty \leq d^*$, which is not possible.

Therefore when the primal problem is unbounded, the dual problem is infeasible.